# How to remove column labels if the name of the label starts with "G" in R programming

Tags: r, dataframe, pdftools, tabulizer

How to remove column labels if the name of the label starts with "G"

**code:**

```
library(pdftools)
library(data.table)
library(tabulizer)
pdf_file <- "new.pdf"

out2 <- extract_tables(pdf_file, pages =c(89), output = "data.frame")
out2<-as.data.table(out2)
colnames(out2)
```

**Actual output:**

```
"Group.1" "Day.7"   "Day.8" "Day.9"
"Group.2" "Day.10" "Day.11", "Day.12"
```

**Expected Output:**

```
"Day.7"   "Day.8" "Day.9"
"Day.10" "Day.11", "Day.12"
```

Also Please please suggest to me any other R packages(other than pdftools and tabulizer) that extract Datatables from PDF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will drop columns that start with `"G"`:

```
result <- out2[, !startsWith(names(out2), "G")]
```

Comment: Also Please please suggest to me any other R packages(other than pdftools and tabulizer) that extract Datatables from PDF

Comment: I've only used `pdftools`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dplyr::select`:

```
library(dplyr)

dplyr::select(out2, -starts_with("G"))
```